# XML deserialization using jackson-dataformat-xml

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm using spring-boot 2.5.4 and I need to deserialize an input xml-file to an object `Person`. Xml looks like this:

```
<person_wrapper>
  <person>
     <firstName>Bob</firstName>
     <lastName>Smith</lastName>
  </person>
</person_wrapper>
```

Class `Person`:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "person")
class Person {
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    
    // getters setters
}
```

How to configure `XmlMapper` to deserialize such xml to the `Person` or how to change `Person` class for it and avoid creating such wrapper:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "person_wrapper")
class PersonWrapper {
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "person")
    private Person person;
  
    // getter setter
}
```

I've found one solution, but I'm not happy with him:

```
XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader streamReader = f.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(inputXml));
streamReader.next(); // to point to <root>
streamReader.next(); // to point to root-element under root

XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
Person person = mapper.readValue(streamReader, Person.class);
streamReader.close();
```

Probably there is another solution to achieve it? I've tried something like this, but unsuccessfully:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.reader()
         .withRootName("person")
         .readValue(inputXml, Person.class);
```

And got

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
> Unrecognized field "person"

If you need any clarification, let me know and thanks in advance.

Comment: Your approach seems me correct, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50057969/read-from-stax-xmlstreamreader-to-unmarshall-partial) can help you  to have a function related to the tag name?

Comment: @dariosicily thanks for sharing! I thought that maybe there is some easier option to do it without using `XMLStreamReader` and so on,  but apparently not, so for now I have chosen this one.

Comment: You are welcome, unfortunately no direct method is available.